# Can someone format into proper sentence structure the lyrics to Por Amar a Ciegas?

Tags: puntuación, letras-de-canciones

These lyrics are posted all over the web in form of lyrical prose.

Because I'm not familiar enough with Spanish, I'm not sure where ideas expressed in this song begin and end. Can someone put this in proper sentence structure, with proper punctuation?

Here's my attempt at the first to paragraphs:

> Yo le pregunté a un pastor del amor y él me dijo, "Que se lo entregara
>   a dios. Que no me sintiera solo. Que estar solo era mejor que vivir de
>   una ilusión."
>
> Yo le pregunté a un artista del amor a primera vista dijo, "Que era un
>   error. Que eso era de un novelista soñadores. Que la vida hay que ser
>   más realista."

Here are the entire lyrics:

> Yo le pregunte a un pastor Del amor y el me dijo Que se lo entregara a
>   dios Que no me sintiera solo Que estar solo era mejor Que vivir de una
>   ilusión
>
> Yo le pregunte a un artista Del amor a primera vista Dijo que era un
>   error Que eso era de un novelista Soñadores que la vida Ay que ser mas
>   realista
>
> Y ahora que no te tengo Pienso en todo el tiempo perdido Que perdí,
>   contigo! Pues por amarte a ciegas yo No escuche Y me lance a si al
>   vació por amor Todos me dijeron, todos me advertían Que hay flores que
>   tienen espinas
>
> Yo le pregunte a un señor Del amor y el me dijo Que ignorarlo era
>   mejor Que yo era joven y el dinero Debería ser mas importante Que mil
>   amores
>
> Yo le pregunte a un anciano En aun lugar lejano Del amor y las
>   pasiones Me dijo Hijo eso es un cristal de doble filo Y corta te
>   guinda de un hilo
>
> Y ahora que no te tengo Pienso en todo el tiempo perdido Que perdí
>   contigo Pues por amarte a ciegas yo No escuche Y me lance a si al
>   vació por amor, Todos me dijeron, todos me advertían Que hay flores
>   que tienen espinas
>
> Yo le pregunta a mi padre Del amor y la inocencia De la fe, y la
>   paciencia sabes lo que dijo Hijo siempre es mejor Ignorar el corazón
>   Hazle caso a tu conciencia
>
> Yo le pregunte a mi madre Del amor que te tenia Dijo que eran
>   fantasías Que si yo no le creía con el tiempo aprendería Que ella
>   tenia razón
>
> Y ahora que no te tengo Pienso en todo el tiempo perdido Que perdí
>   contigo! Pues por amarte a ciegas yo No escuche Y me lance a si al
>   vació por amor Todos me dijeron, todos me advertían Que hay flores que
>   tienen espinas

Comment: Well, I don't think there's any way to edit this question to make this "on-topic". Should I just delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the song @ youtube, so based on the singing and overall song context...I'd say (in my perspective), punctutation goes like this:

Yo le pregunté a un pastor, del amor; y él me dijo, que se lo entregara a Dios.
Que no me sintiera solo; que estar solo era mejor que vivir de una ilusión.

Yo le pregunté a un artista, del amor a primera vista...y dijo que era un error.
Que eso era de novelistas, soñadores...que en la vida, hay que ser más realistas.

Y ahora que no te tengo, pienso en todo el tiempo perdido...que perdí, contigo.
Pues por amarte a ciegas yo...no escuché; y me lance al vacío por amor.

Todos me dijeron...todos me advertían...que hay flores que tienen espinas.

Yo le pregunté a un señor, del amor, y él me dijo que ignorarlo era mejor. Que yo era joven, y el dinero; debería ser más importante que mil amores.

Yo le pregunté a un anciano, en un algún lugar lejano, del amor y las pasiones...
Me dijo: -"Hijo, eso es un cristal de doble filo, y corta. Te guinda de un hilo".

Yo le pregunté a mi Padre, del amor y la inocencia; de la fé, la paciencia...y sabes lo que dijo?
Dijo: -"Siempre es mejor Ignorar el corazón, hazle caso a tu consciencia".

Yo le pregunté a mi Madre, del amor que te tenía...y dijo que eran fantasías. Que si yo no le creía, con el tiempo aprendería...que ella tenia razón.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps tremendously! How'd you like the song?

Comment: I'm glad this helped. Well, not my cup of tea, but lyrics are definitely interesting ;).